# List of Tuples (string, float)with NaN How to get the min value?

Tags: python, list, tuples, nan, min

I have a list of List of Tuples (string, float) with `float('nan')`. How can i get the tuple with the smallest number? If I use min I always get the `nan`.

```
[('GroundBasedMechWT', nan), ('GroundBasedCTL', nan), ('GroundBasedManualWT', nan), ('GroundBasedManualLog', nan), ('CableManualWTLog', 60.77), ('CableManualWT', 58.52), ('CableManualLog', 68.17), ('CableManualCTL', nan), ('HelicopterManualWT', 96.82), ('HelicopterManualCTL', nan)]
```

Comment: Is it `NaN`?  `np.NaN`?

Comment: NameError: name 'nan' is not defined. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am sorry. It is float('NaN').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
min(filter(lambda t: not math.isnan(t[1]), l), key=itemgetter(1))
```

where `itemgetter` refers to [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom key, that will return a very high value for `NaN`:

```
min(list, key=lambda x: float('inf') if math.isnan(x[1]) else x[1])
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong -- it should be `key=lambda x: ...` and this won't work as `float('nan') == float('nan')` will never be `True`. (Thank the IEEE committee for that one!)

Comment: well then I could also substitute my NaN wit inf. I will still not get the min number in return.

Comment: Yep.  I see.  That should work.  +1.  I knew there had to be an `isnan` floating around somewhere (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> nan=float('NaN')
>>> x=[('GroundBasedMechWT', nan), ('GroundBasedCTL', nan), ('GroundBasedManualWT', nan), ('GroundBasedManualLog', nan), ('CableManualWTLog', 60.77), ('CableManualWT', 58.52), ('CableManualLog', 68.17), ('CableManualCTL', nan), ('HelicopterManualWT', 96.82), ('HelicopterManualCTL', nan)]
>>> nan<1
False
>>> nan<1.0
False
>>> min(x)
('CableManualCTL', nan)
```

I don't think nan is considered smaller than regular floats. Probably min is comparing the strings alphabetically.

(Not a complete answer, but might help)

Comment: I don't think this should be an answer (maybe a comment instead).

Comment: Try `1 < nan` and `1.0 < nan`, and you'll get the same result (`False`). Even `nan == nan` should return `False`. But you're right in that, if comparing tuples using the default comparator, it will first sort the first element alphabetically, then use the second if two have the same first element.

Comment: @A.R.S.: I fear I just couldn't express it as clearly without a fair bit of code

Answer (score 0):

```
nan=float('NaN')
x=[('GroundBasedMechWT', nan), ('GroundBasedCTL', nan), ('GroundBasedManualWT', nan), ('GroundBasedManualLog', nan), ('CableManualWTLog', 60.77), ('CableManualWT', 58.52), ('CableManualLog', 68.17), ('CableManualCTL', nan), ('HelicopterManualWT', 96.82), ('HelicopterManualCTL', nan)]
val=('foo', float('Inf')) #thanks for teaching me that
for tup in x:
    if tup[1]<val[1]:
        val=tup
print val
```

Fails on the empty list, but otherwise solves the problem.